# Copy 3gp moov atom from one file to another

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, 3gp

I was in Norway and I had an awesome time; I recorded my ride on the sledges, and my HTC Sensation turned off when I finished my ride because my battery ran out.

When I reached my laptop I found a 630 Mb video file my the phone, but I was not able to play it with VLC. Since I'm using **Ubuntu**, I tried to `ffprobe` my file and I received the following:

```
[22:22 @ ~/Desktop] $ ffprobe VIDEO0002.3gp 
FFprobe version 0.6-4:0.6-2ubuntu6.3, Copyright (c) 2007-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 21 2011 18:43:14 with gcc 4.4.5
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6-2ubuntu6.3 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x8c3c010]moov atom not found
VIDEO0002.3gp: Operation not permitted
```

I had an idea that I might be able to use an older recorded video from my phone and simply copy the moov atom from that working file to the broken one. Any ideas about that? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just ran into a very similar problem...

Comment: I was able to fix this by following the instructions at http://superuser.com/a/596402/83682

Answer (score 1):

This could be happening due to various reasons. See [ffmpeg - moov atom not found](http://blog.alwayshere.info/2011/01/ffmpeg-moov-atom-not-found.html).